# Google Sheets Concatenate Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to javascript and a novice coder.  I have been trying to write a simple script for a Google Sheet to concatenate two columns of data into another column:
[image: google sheet]

My script below runs fine but only produces Aaron Ward as line 1 of Desired Column C.  I'm sure it is really simple what I am missing, but if anyone has a minute to help a rookie, I'd really appreciate it.

```
function concatenate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var values1 = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, lr, 1);
  var values2 = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 2, lr, 1);
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
    results = [values1[i] + " " + values2[i]];
    Logger.log(results);
    sheet.getRange(1, 3, results.length).setValues([results]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This happens because 1) you always grab row 1, column 3, with length of 1 row, and 2) you write within the loop, rather than collecting the row data into the output array and then writing once done looping.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Writing inside loop was main problem, I got it working like this (not sure if cleanest):  

    function concatenate() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
      var values1 = sheet.getSheetValues(1,1,lr,2);
      Logger.log(values1);
      var results = [];
      for (var i=0; i<lr; i++) {
        results[i] = [values1[i][0]+" "+values1[i][1]];
        Logger.log(results);
       }
       sheet.getRange(1,3,results.length).setValues(results);
    }

Comment: Consider using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and/or [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to simplify your code / increase its expressiveness. Feel free to also submit your fixed code as an answer if you feel it will be useful to others, or delete the question if you think it will not

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a formula? In C1 place the formula `=JOIN(“ “,A1:B1)` and drag it to the last row.

Comment: This sheet populates from form responses, and when a new form response comes in, it creates a new row and doesn't inherit any formulas that have been previously dragged to the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. In your for-loop, you need to [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the concatenated string into your `results` array. Then you can `setValues(results)` after the for-loop.

```
function concatenate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var values1 = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, lr, 1);
  var values2 = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 2, lr, 1);
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
    results.push([values1[i] + " " + values2[i]]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 3, results.length).setValues(results);
}
```

Comment: Op solved in comments :) (and removed one of the double reads - you have both still ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can either use this

```
function conCat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("your sheet name")
  var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues()
  for(var k = 1;k<data.length;k++){
        var row = data[k]
        var merge = row[0]+" "+row[1]
        ws.getRange(k+1,3).setValue(merge)
     }
   }
```

This code will simply take values from first and second column and concatenate result will show in third column